# Scroll page while dragging image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sorry if it is already asked, but I'm stuck on this. I'm making a website atm. In that website I have a page with around 100 images. The user can sort that page by dragging them into place. The problem is it is impossible to get all images on the screen. So if you have a image on the bottom which needs to be on the top, you'll have to scroll your way up. I know if you hold the picture at the bottom on the screen it will scroll too. But my users don't seem to understand :P.

Code:

```
<div style="height:1000px;">
<img src="http://go.3fm.nl/data/thumb/abc_media_image/1000/1716/w456.015c6_r16-9_57ac1e644a2466ac4c5fa5aab5986e29.jpg"/> 
</div>
```

Problem is I can't make it work. I made a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/j2194re7/) which has the same issue. My question:

How can I drag and scroll with my mouse at the same time?

Comment: your example is not loading any js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue of windows. Fixed it by checking the sreeny variable of event. If its to high, scroll down. To low = scroll up